# jQuery UI sortable w/ list padding -- cannot drop over number

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/k19o7adr/)

html

```
<ol id="input-l8YFwLZvwNZ4" class="infinitext-lis">
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="answers[0[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text">
        <input type="hidden" name="answers[0][order]">
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <input type="text" name="answers[1[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text">
        <input type="hidden" name="answers[1][order]">
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

js

```
$('#input-l8YFwLZvwNZ4').sortable();
```

When you grab one of the list items by the number and drag it up or down over top of one of the other list numbers, they don't move and allow you to drop the list item there. You have to pick an item up, move your mouse to the right and drop it over one of the text boxes instead.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Consider [raising a bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k19o7adr/1/

There is some problem with ordered list with sortable, so i have changed it to ul tag and all is working fine now.

```js
$('#input2').sortable();
```

```html
<ul id="input2" class="infinitext-lis">
    <li>1.
        <input type="text" name="answers[0[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[0][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li class="">2.
        <input type="text" name="answers[1[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[1][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li class="">3.
        <input type="text" name="answers[4[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[4][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li>4.
        <input type="text" name="answers[2[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[2][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li class="">5.
        <input type="text" name="answers[5[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[5][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li>6.
        <input type="text" name="answers[6[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[6][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li class="">7.
        <input type="text" name="answers[3[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[3][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li class="">8.
        <input type="text" name="answers[7[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[7][order]"/>
    </li>
    <li>9.
        <input type="text" name="answers[8[text]" style="width:275px" class="infinitext-text"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="answers[8][order]"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't really change anything. Grab the list items by the bullet points instead of the numbers -- it has the exact same problem. The reason you can grab the elements by the numbers is because you've moved them into the list item.